# Converting log file timestamps from 12-hour time format to 24-hour time format

Tags: bash, awk, sed, timestamp, logfile

I have a number of large, space delimited, WhatsApp chat logs that I need to convert the timestamps from 12-hour time format to 24-hour time format.

95% of the content of these files maintain the same line format as follows:

MM/DD/YY,|HH:MM|XM|-|participant:|chatText

However, there are a few instances spread throughout these chat logs that do not maintain the standard line format as shown above.

Here is a sample of the logs:

```
5/30/22, 9:50 AM - person2: Good morning
5/30/22, 11:35 AM - person1: Hi, how are you?
5/30/22, 11:47 AM - person2: I am well
Transfer number: 3778324
Completed:
5/30/22, 12:55 PM - person1: https://mylink.com
5/30/22, 12:59 PM - person2: <Media omitted>
5/30/22, 9:46 PM - person1: thanks
```

Here are the requirements:

1. Accept input from a log file
2. Output changes as either in-place or separate out-file
3. Change all instances of HH:MM XM in the 2nd space delimited position to 24-hour format
4. Do not make any changes to the non-standard formatted lines
5. Prefer not to have to install any extra development environments

This is a sample of what it should look like after changes:

```
5/30/22, 09:50 - person2: Good morning
5/30/22, 11:35 - person1: Hi, how are you?
5/30/22, 11:47 - person2: I am well
Transfer number: 3778324
Completed:
5/30/22, 12:55 - person1: https://mylink.com
5/30/22, 12:59 - person2: <Media omitted>
5/30/22, 21:46 - person1: thanks
```

This is what I've been able to come up with so far, but I can't figure out how to get beyond the HH position, nor do I have any clue how I will avoid making changes to the non-standard formatted lines:

`echo "5/30/22, 9:46 PM - person1: thanks"\ |awk -F' ' 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}{("date --date=\""$2 $3"\" +%H:$M") |getline $2;print }'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are any of the spaces in your input actually tab characters? If so please run `cat -A file` (or similar) on the input and [edit] your question to show the result so we can see where the tabs are.

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 ~ "^([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{2},$" {
    split($2,t,":")
    if ( ($3 == "PM") && (t[1] < 12) ) {
        t[1] += 12
    }
    time = sprintf(" %02d:%02d ", t[1], t[2])
    sub(/ [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M /,time)
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
5/30/22, 09:50 - person2: Good morning
5/30/22, 11:35 - person1: Hi, how are you?
5/30/22, 11:47 - person2: I am well
Transfer number: 3778324
Completed:
5/30/22, 12:55 - person1: https://mylink.com
5/30/22, 12:59 - person2: <Media omitted>
5/30/22, 21:46 - person1: thanks
```

The above uses `sub()` to change `$0` instead of directly changing `$2` and `$3` so that it will not change any white space on the lines that start with a timestamp (tabs and/or chains of blanks would be converted to single blanks if it changed `$2` or `$3` directly), e.g. changing `$0` with the above script:

```
$ cat file1
5/30/22, 9:50 AM - person2: Good      morning

$ awk -f tst.awk file1
5/30/22, 09:50 - person2: Good      morning
```

vs if it changed `$2` directly (note the change in white space between `Good` and `morning`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 ~ "^([0-9]{1,2}/){2}[0-9]{2},$" {
    split($2,t,":")
    if ( ($3 == "PM") && (t[1] < 12) ) {
        t[1] += 12
    }
    $2 = sprintf("%02d:%02d", t[1], t[2])
    sub(/ [AP]M /," ")
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1
5/30/22, 09:50 - person2: Good morning
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and the explanation of how it works. I apologize, however, I should have been more specific that I was using gawk. I tried this solution using gawk and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @dotarpa as I mentioned at the top of my answer the solution I posted will work in any POSIX-compliant awk which includes gawk (which I used when running it in my answer). If it isn't working for you then either you copy/pasted it incorrectly or your real input doesn't look like the example you posted. As you can see in my answer, given the sample input you provided the script will produce the expected output you provided.

Comment: Having said that - what is the output of `awk --version` on your machine? Very old versions of gawk would require the `--re-interval` flag added to enable POSIX RE intervals like `{1,2}`.

Comment: works like a CHAMP! I plead the 5th :)

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
5/30/22, 9:50 AM - person2: Good morning
5/30/22, 11:35 AM - person1: Hi, how are you?
5/30/22, 11:47 AM - person2: I am well
Transfer number: 3778324
Completed:
5/30/22, 12:55 PM - person1: https://mylink.com
5/30/22, 12:59 PM - person2: <Media omitted>
5/30/22, 9:46 PM - person1: thanks
```

then

```
awk '$3~/^[AP]M$/{split($2,arr,":");if($3=="PM"&&arr[1]<12){arr[1]+=12};$2=sprintf("%02d:%02d",arr[1],arr[2])}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
5/30/22, 09:50 AM - person2: Good morning
5/30/22, 11:35 AM - person1: Hi, how are you?
5/30/22, 11:47 AM - person2: I am well
Transfer number: 3778324
Completed:
5/30/22, 12:55 PM - person1: https://mylink.com
5/30/22, 12:59 PM - person2: <Media omitted>
5/30/22, 21:46 PM - person1: thanks
```

Explanation: for lines where 3rd field is AM or PM, do split 2nd field at `:` character and put result of that into array `arr`, if 3rd field is `PM` and 1st element of array (i.e. hour) is less than 12 increase it by 12, set 2nd field to `HH:MM` where HH is hour, zero-padded to width of 2, MM is minute, zero-padded to width of 2. Independently from such change made or not `print` line. If you want to know more about `split` or `sprintf` then read [String Functions (The GNU Awk Users Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). Observe that I do not set `FS` or `OFS` as defaults are fine for presented task.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: answer is incorrect since last line shifted by wrong amount

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto right, I did typo in my code, I fixed it

Comment: Thanks for this solution and explanation of how it works. It appears to be changing the HH:MM to the correct 24-hour format, however, it does not appear to be removing the AM/PM portion. I probably should have been more specific in my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun, and because you tagged `sed`, here is a solution with GNU `sed` and `date`. But don't use this on large files, it would be far slower than the excellent other `awk` solutions: for each line to modify it executes one `date` command with the shell.

```
$ sed -E 'h;s!^(\S+),(\s+\S+\s+[AP]M\>).*!date -d "\1 \2" +"%D, %R"!e;T;G;s!\n(\s*\S+){3}!!' file.log
05/30/22, 09:50 - person2: Good morning
05/30/22, 11:35 - person1: Hi, how are you?
05/30/22, 11:47 - person2: I am well
Transfer number: 3778324
Completed:
05/30/22, 12:55 - person1: https://mylink.com
05/30/22, 12:59 - person2: <Media omitted>
05/30/22, 21:46 - person1: thanks
```

Explanations: the `e` flag of the substitute command executes the content of the pattern space with the shell and replaces the pattern space with the output.

- We first copy the input line in the hold space (`h`) such that we can later extract the trailing part.
- If the line in the pattern space is `DATE, HOUR [AP]M <SOMETHING>`, we replace it with `date -d "DATE HOUR [AP]M" +"%D, %R"`, execute that with the shell, and replace the pattern space with the output, thanks to the `e` flag.
- If the line was a "*non-standard formatted line*", there has been no substitution, we print it and move to the next line (`T`).
- Else we append a newline and the hold space to the pattern space (`G`), which becomes:

  ```
  DATE, NEWHOUR-newline-DATE, OLDHOUR [AP]M <SOMETHING>
  ```

  We delete `newline-DATE, OLDHOUR [AP]M` and print.

Comment: this one seems to be changing all the HH:MM,s to 00:00, but is, however, successfully removing the AM/PM portion

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.7

Comment: Oops, sorry after my last edit, I forgot a `\2` group in the replacement string. Fixed.

Comment: @"Renaud Pacalet" yep that fixed it. Pretty cool seeing how it can be done with sed too. thxs